# Vim :find does not work as expect

Tags: vim

I expect to search and edit files in my project with VIM editor.

VIM is started with pwd = Project/root

I use `:find fileName` to find and edit files lies under project root directory.

```
:setlocal path+=Project/root
```

command added Project/root to path option.

And I confirm the previous command with `:set path?`

the `:find fileName` command does not work for some of the files.

What did I miss?

Comment: Try `setlocal path+=Project/root/**`.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to edit a file in the pwd you can just type `:e <start of file name><tab>` to tab through files starting with a certain name.